# How to print a new object's property value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I'm working on a list app where initially the user is presented with an input and button. In the input the user enters the name of a new list, and after the button is clicked, an empty list appears ready for input of items. Adding a new list works, as does adding/removing list items. But the name of the list doesn't print on the page. Currently without any advanced CSS, it's expected for the lists' names to all appear at the top of the page rather than directly above their respective lists.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVmeLe

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="notepadApp">
    <div ng-controller="notepadController as notepadCtrl">
        <header ng-repeat="list in notepadCtrl.lists">
            <form name="removeListForm" ng-submit="notepadCtrl.removeList($index)">
                <input type="submit" value="Remove list">
            </form>
            <h1>{{list.name}}</h1>
        </header>
        <div ng-repeat="list in notepadCtrl.lists" class="shoppingList" ng-controller="ItemController as itemCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in list.items">

                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
                        <span class="item-name-wrapper">{{item.name}}</span>
                    </label>
                    <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.removeItem(list, $index)">
                        <input type="submit" value="remove">
                    </form>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.addItem(list)">
                <input type="text" ng-model="itemCtrl.item.name">
                <input type="submit" value="Add item">
            </form>
        </div>

        <form name="addListForm" ng-submit="notepadCtrl.addList(newListName)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="notepadCtrl.list.name">
            <input type="submit" value="Add list">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('notepadApp', []);

var shoppingLists = [

];

app.controller('notepadController', function(){
    var notepadCtrl = this;

    notepadCtrl.lists = shoppingLists;

    notepadCtrl.addList = function(newListName) {
        var newList = {
            name: newListName,
            items:[]
        };

        shoppingLists.push(newList);
    };

    notepadCtrl.removeList = function(index) {
        shoppingLists.splice(index, 1);
    };

});

app.controller('ItemController', function(){
    this.item = {};

    this.addItem = function(list){
        list.items.push(this.item);
        this.item = {};
    };

    this.removeItem = function(list, index) {
        list.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to replace:

```
ng-submit="notepadCtrl.addList(newListName)"
```

with:

```
ng-submit="notepadCtrl.addList(notepadCtrl.list.name)"
```

Comment: I see - So in this case the ng-model attribute describes what key the inputted text will be the value of, therefore, that value has to be passed into the addList function.